# UITextView inside PrototypeCell have different behavior in two iPhone simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I've a `UITableView` with two cells to user put information.

First cell: Two buttons to "cancel" and "done".
Second cell: A `UITextView` to user type information.

This works fine in iPhone 7, 6s... but in the iPhone SE and 5C the screen is different. I used auto-layout and in the storyboard appears works fine.
Detail: I needed set `Height Constraint` to TextView to works.

The difference can be seen on the image below:

[image]

Storyboard:

[image]

TableView`s constraints:

[image]

ViewController:

```
class LiberarViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewForm: UITableView!

    var callback : ((String)-> ())?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableViewForm.dataSource = self
        tableViewForm.delegate = self
//        tableViewForm.tableFooterView = UIView()        
    }

    @objc func cancelar(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
    }

    @objc func finalizar(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("End edigint: \(textView.text!)")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 1 {
            return "Digite a justificativa: "
        }
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {
            case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellBotoesLiberar") as! CellBotoesLiberar
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.btCancelar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelar), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.btFinalizar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(finalizar), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell

        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellJustificativaLiberar") as! CellJustificativaLiberar
            cell.txtViewJustificativa.delegate = self
            return cell

            default: return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
}

class CellJustificativaLiberar : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtViewJustificativa: UITextView!
}

class CellBotoesLiberar : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var btFinalizar: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btCancelar: UIButton!
}
```

Comment: What constraints you have set for TableView?

Comment: I've edited.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TableView's top constraint to Safe Area is causing problem. Add below constraints:

1. Horizpntally and Vertically center to superview.
2. Fix Height and Fix width/ Leading and Trailing to Superview.

Hope this will works for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works, you can explain to me why Top constraint is a problem? And, if I want automatic expandable View's height to user put long text?

Comment: @Augusto You have set Horizontally center constraint to tableview and set top also AutoLayout engine will try to center your tableview first rather than maitain it's height. This is causing issue.

Comment: @Augusto for expandable TextView height you need to set `textView.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
textView.isScrollEnabled = false` and need to set height constraint priority of UITextView to Low.

Comment: If I need put a new Cell with a big View, I need change the Height Constraint?

Comment: Yes, if you want new cell with big view should display in screen without scroll.

Comment: There are a way to make this without set height constraint?

Comment: You can remove height constraint and add top and bottom constraint. There are two ways only.

Comment: I did this, but only the first cell keeping appearing -> https://imgur.com/a/M6Otbki

Comment: Give 20 top and 20 bottom.

Comment: The constraints lines became red and UITableView shows large blank space.

Comment: I think that the best way to me is set height constraint programatically when needed

Comment: @Augusto Yes, Set programmatically will work for you.

Comment: I could do what I wanted, but the `UIPickerView` is not centralized on the cell, do you can help me? -> https://imgur.com/a/uIHTlDR